# Angular 2 send event from parent to all children

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement a simple menu bar. I have a main menu bar component and many sub-menus that can be of various depths. I want to close every sub-menu when closing the main menu bar. So I would like the parent component to send a simple event without any data to every child.

I would like to do this without having to declare any input when using a sub-menu component because this event subscription is mandatory and is the same for every sub-menu. So the declaration will be much more simple and will avoid further mistakes.

In other words, I have this in menu-bar component:

```
<sub-menu [title]="File">
    <sub-menu [title]="New" (onclick)="newFile()"></sub-menu>
    <sub-menu [title]="Open" (onclick)="openFile()"></sub-menu>
    <sub-menu [title]="Save" (onclick)="saveFile()"></sub-menu>
</sub-menu>
<sub-menu [title]="Edit">
    <sub-menu [title]="Copy" (onclick)="copy()"></sub-menu>
    <sub-menu [title]="Paste" (onclick)="paste()"></sub-menu>
</sub-menu>
```

and want this parent component to send an event to every sub-menu without having to declare anything like this :

```
<sub-menu [title]="File" [mainClosed]="closed">
    <sub-menu [title]="New" (onclick)="newFile()" [mainClosed]="closed"></sub-menu>
    <sub-menu [title]="Open" (onclick)="openFile()" [mainClosed]="closed"></sub-menu>
    <sub-menu [title]="Save" (onclick)="saveFile()" [mainClosed]="closed"></sub-menu>
</sub-menu>
<sub-menu [title]="Edit" [mainClosed]="closed">
    <sub-menu [title]="Copy" (onclick)="copy()" [mainClosed]="closed"></sub-menu>
    <sub-menu [title]="Paste" (onclick)="paste()" [mainClosed]="closed"></sub-menu>
</sub-menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@ViewChildren` to inject the child components into the parent as ViewChildren

In your parent component you need to define something similar to this

```ts
import { ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

export class parentMenuComponent {

    @ViewChildren(SubMenu) allSubMenus: QueryList<SubMenu>;
    ...

    constructor() { }

    closeAll(){
        this.allSubMenus.forEach((subMenu) => subMenu.close());
    }
}
```

Where `SubMenu` is the child component's name

More information on how `@ViewChild` & `@ViewChildren` work can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child)

Comment: THANK YOU! I want to kiss you.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to have helped, but perhaps save the physical affection to someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

```ts
@Injectable() 
class MenuShared {
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  readonly close:Observable = this.subject.asObservable();

  notifyClose() {
    this.subject.next(true);
  }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'sub-menu',
  providers: [MenuShared]
})
export class SubMenuComponent {
  constructor(
      private menuShared:MenuShared, 
      @SkipSelf() @Optional() private parentMenuShared:MenuShared) {
    parentMenuShared.close.subscribe((_) => {
      this.closed = true;
      this.onClose();
  }
  onClose() {
    this.menuShared.notifyClose();
  }
}
```

This way a each menu can share a service instance with itself and it's children. It can subscribe to parent notifications to close itself, and notify childs about itself being closed.

`@SkipSelf()` is to not get the instance from itself.
`@Optional()` is to not get an error on the root menu, which can't inject from the parent.